# Отмена повторной отправки формы

Tags: php

Есть код проверки формы

```
<?
//Если форма отправлена
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if (md5($_POST['norobot']) <> $_SESSION['randomnr2']) {
        $hasError = true;
    }
    //Проверка Поля ИМЯ
    if (trim($_POST['contactname']) == '') {
        $hasError = true;
    } else {
        $name = trim($_POST['contactname']);
    }
    //Проверка правильности ввода EMAIL
    if (trim($_POST['email']) == '') {
        $hasError = true;
    } else
    if (!eregi("^[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9._%-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$", trim($_POST['email']))) {
        $hasError = true;
    } else {
        $email = trim($_POST['email']);
    }
    //Проверка наличия ТЕКСТА сообщения
    if (trim($_POST['message']) == '') {
        $hasError = true;
    } else {
        if (function_exists('stripslashes')) {
            $comments = stripslashes(trim($_POST['message']));
        } else {
            $comments = trim($_POST['message']);
        }
    }
    //Если ошибок нет, отправить email
    if (!isset($hasError)) {
        $emailTo = 'darlex.box@hotmail.com'; //Сюда введите Ваш email
        $body = "Name: $name \n\nEmail: $email \n\nComments:\n $comments";
        $headers = 'From: My Site <'.$emailTo.'>' . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: ' . $email;
        mail($emailTo, $subject, $body, $headers);
        $emailSent = true;
    }
}
?>
```

Нужно отменить повторную отправку формы. Слышал о `header('Location:'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);`, но куда его вставить и как правильно оформить?

Comment: @maestro зачем вы испортили форматирование в ПП ?

Comment: @Эдуард, Что значит "испортил"? Я доработал авторское форматирование, и похоже, что мы с вами сделали это одновременно. Что такое ПП?

Comment: @maestro вероятно, ПП — предлагаемая правка.

Comment: @Эдуард думаю, что maestro ничего сознательно не портил. Просто он начал редактировать вопрос раньше, чем вы предложили правку — и не знал, что кто-то ещё редактирует вопрос. Потом автор утвердил вашу правку, потом правку maestro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вставьте `die(header('Location:'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']));` в блок *//Если ошибок нет, отправить email* :

```
//Если ошибок нет, отправить email
if (!isset($hasError)) {
    $emailTo = 'darlex.box@hotmail.com'; //Сюда введите Ваш email
    $body = "Name: $name \n\nEmail: $email \n\nComments:\n $comments";
    $headers = 'From: My Site <'.$emailTo.'>' . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: ' . $email;
    mail($emailTo, $subject, $body, $headers);
    $emailSent = true;

    die(header('Location:'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']));
}
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66815/discussion-on-answer-by-----).